# Where should I define business logics in VIPER Architecture in iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

I have used different architectures and I'm kind of new to VIPER architecture. I used to do all the business logics in the Model Class. Is this the best practice for VIPER as well or is there any standard way of doing this in VIPER architecture, specifically in iOS, Swift?

Comment: [https://github.com/erimkurt/App-Store-VIPER](https://github.com/erimkurt/App-Store-VIPER)

Answer (score 0):

The business logic in a VIPER module resides in the Interactor, whereas the Presenter contains view logic and prepares content to be consumed by the view. As a simple example, if your Presenter needs to display information it would ask your Interactor to fetch it from a data source.

I found this article to be pretty useful for getting started with VIPER: https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/

Comment: Mmm not necessarily. I would argue that the Interactor should just interact and it’s the Presenter that does the thinking. Proof: you can write an app or module with no Interactors but every module needs a Presenter.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "just interact" but the pattern you are describing is probably more similar to MVP. In VIPER you further separate the concerns of presentation and business logic into Presenters and Interactors. The Presenter has logic of when and how to present information to the user (e.g. when to show a list of to-dos), whereas the Interactor contains logic to manipulate your model objects (e.g. fetch todo models and sort them).

Answer (score 0):

As explained in
https://theswiftdev.com/the-ultimate-viper-architecture-tutorial
the presenter zone is where business logic is implemented.  The interactor zone is for the actual acquisition from sensor, database, network, etc.  Yes, at some level of rudimentary concepts the actual correct operation of the sensor is a kind of business logic; the operation of the database (especially if it has stored procedures) is a kind of business logic; obeying the networking protocol's rules & formats is a kind of business logic, but that 'business' is a low-level business of infrastructure the bread-&-butter app-domain business for which the higher-order software app is being written in VIPER.

Hence, the presenter zone is where business logic for the app should reside, with the interactor focused solely on what it takes to accomplish the operation of the infrastructural mechanics of the data acquisition itself.

Answer (score -2):

- **Presenter**
  It is responsible for view initiating the calls generated by UI. It also updates UI when some data is received.
- **Interactor**
  It logic code goes here. It will return the results to presenter and presenter will send data to UI for updates.

Here is a Swift demo app developed in VIPER architecutre. I hope it will help
https://github.com/anisrehman/MoviesDemo-VIPER

Comment: I improved my answer. I hope it is helpful now.